# After installing Apache server the website home page works but links under it give 404

Tags: 20.04, apache2, mysql, wordpress

I've just installed apache and mysql on my system and a copy of Wordpress from my production server.

When I access the website, the home page loads perfectly, but if I click any other link with the website I get:

Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

I've searched high and low online and most of these posts are regarding permalinks, but this problem affects all pages within my site.
I tried updating the apache2.conf file to AllowOverride All in each 3 sections, as some suggested this could be the cause but this has not fixed it:

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you're missing `.htaccess` in the web root, or `mod_rewrite` is not enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a way to fix this:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```